# Android window title bar icon is causing background for list view items

Tags: android, android-layout

Programmatic setting the window title bar icon is causing every list view item has tile bar icon as background.

`setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.ball);`

How can i remove the listview background image or set the window title bar icon any other way than programmatic?

With window title icon set

[image]

With out window title icon

[image]

--UPDATE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Sets the text styles -->
<resources>
     <style name="CustomWindowTitleText" parent="android:TextAppearance.WindowTitle">
          <item name="android:textSize">24dip</item>
          <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
          <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item> 
          <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
     </style>
     <!-- Changes the background color of the title bar -->
     <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
           <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_gradient_05</item>
           <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
     </style>
     <!-- Set the theme for the window title -->
     <!-- NOTE: setting android:textAppearence to style defined above -->
     <style name="CustomWindowTitle" parent="android:WindowTitle">
          <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomWindowTitleText</item>
          <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
          <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
          <item name="android:shadowRadius">0</item>
          <item name="android:shadowColor">#a0a0a0</item>
      </style>
      <!-- Override properties in the default theme -->
      <!-- NOTE: you must explicitly the windowTitleSize property, the title bar will not re-size automatically, text will be clipped -->
      <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
           <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dip</item>
           <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitle</item>
           <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
      </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: why dont you using a custom title bar?

Comment: @Tanmay Mandal already using custom titlebar

Comment: woww..... Sweepshots luk hav changed.....!!!

Comment: parent="android:WindowTitle" no longer works in newer SDKs. It's a private style. Same probleme as android:AlertDialog . Np replacement yet. TextAppearance_WindowTitle  is something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the  following code

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);
```

Please be sure that you are using `requestWindowFeature` before `setContentView`.Here  in `R.layout.custom_title`  use your custom title xml.

I think this will help you.

Comment: @Tanmay Mandal I'm doing it already, but issue still occurs whenever the orientation changes

Comment: Use two diffrenent layout for landscape/protrait

Comment: @Tanmay Mandal right now thee are 3 layout used here, one for main activity and two othres for the tabs

Comment: If you look into my answer I have told you to use a custom  layout for your title..But you are doing something else....I told you to use `getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);` but you are using `setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.ball);`

Comment: oops.. let me try that `setFeatureInt`.. i didn't notice it.